# How do I make a POST request from within a django function to rest api?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have xyz.py file. In this file I have a function

```
@api_view(['POST']) 
def abc(request):
```

which can be accessible at a url, say */algorithms/abc*.

I have another function

```
def pkr():
```

I want to make POST request from this function to `abc(request)`. I tried 
`requests.request('POST', "/algorithms/abc", data=data_input)` but the `request.data` at `abc(request)` is received as QueryDict (& not dict) & looses some texts that existed in `data_input` inside `pkr()` function.

Comment: No you don't. Why would you want to do that? Why incur all the overhead of serializing, going via the internet, deserializing etc, when you're just calling within your own app?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks so much for the reply. In this case, how would I call abc(request) function directly? It is expecting a request object because inside I get data by "payload = request.data".  sorry if this trivial - i am new to django.

Comment: You should think at a higher level. Where is the data in `pkr` coming from? Why do you want to send it to `abc`? What will `abc` do with that data? Is there some logic that could be abstracted out of `abc` and called directly from `pkr`?

Comment: That is the reason why **controllers** exist. When some piece of functionality can be used by several clientes (like is your case), you'll rather abstract it, so you can call it from both `abc()` and `pkr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what @Daniel_Roseman and @Hugo_Luis_Villalobos_Canto is saying in comment.

We can abstract (refactor out) the logic to process the data in some separate function and then re-use the same function at both places by passing data to it.

Something like this :

```
def process_data(data):
    # process your data here
    print(data)


@api_view(['POST']) 
def abc(request):
    data = request.POST
    process_data(data)


def pkr():
    process_data(data)
```